# Fusing two reduction operations in cuda Thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

Is there a way to do a `reduce_by_key` operation and a `reduce` (or ideally another `reduce_by_key`) operation in only one kernel call in Thrust? Besides gaining computational speed, let us say I want to do this because the number of output values from the first `reduce_by_key` operation is too large to be stored in memory.

I have been wondering if `transform_output_iterator` could help here but have not found a solution.

A simple demonstration, but not my real use case, could be to find the minimum of the maximums of each row in a matrix, where that matrix is flattened and stored in a `device_vector`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure your solution solves my example problem, I have to think more. Also in general my segments will not all be of the same length. But in the meantime, regarding my comment about memory, you can imagine the matrix values are generated from a counting iterator and a transform iterator, and there are several billions of them.

Comment: Sorry, I missread. My description is for finding both the minima and the maxima, not the minima **of** the maxima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code computes the minimum of all row maximums with a fixed amount of temporary storage to store a limited number of minima. Afterwards, a min reduce is performed to find the global minimum

The idea is to directly update the minimum value via transform_output_iterator. This can be done via atomics (in case of raw pointers for temp minima) or via locks (in case of iterators for temp minima. not shown in this answer).

To avoid atomic contention, the number of temporary minima should not be too small.

For 1G segments of size 1,i.e. there will be an atomic operation for each input element, I observe the following timings on an A100 GPU.

```
time approach 1 (standard): 13.2674 ms.
time approach 2 (fused): 38.0479 ms. (minimaSlots = 1)
time approach 2 (fused): 23.9251 ms. (minimaSlots = 1024)
time approach 2 (fused): 10.1109 ms. (minimaSlots = 1024 * 1024)
```

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_output_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

template<size_t size>
struct UpdateMinimumOp{
    int* minPtr;

    UpdateMinimumOp(int* ptr):minPtr(ptr){}
    __device__
    int operator()(int value){
     // select output slot for minimum based on thread id
        const size_t pos = size_t(threadIdx.x) + size_t(blockIdx.x) * size_t(blockDim.x);
        const size_t minPos = pos % size;

        atomicMin(minPtr + minPos, value);
        return value;
    }
};

int main(){
    cudaEvent_t a; cudaEventCreate(&a);
    cudaEvent_t b; cudaEventCreate(&b);
    float t; 

    size_t N =  1ull << 30;
    thrust::device_vector<int> keys(N);
    thrust::device_vector<int> values(N);
    thrust::sequence(keys.begin(), keys.end(), 0);
    thrust::sequence(values.begin(), values.end(), 1);

    //Approach 1 (for timing comparison). max Reduce_by_key. then min reduce
    thrust::device_vector<int> maxima(N);

    cudaEventRecord(a);

    thrust::reduce_by_key(
        keys.begin(),
        keys.end(),
        values.begin(),
        thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
        maxima.begin(),
        thrust::equal_to<int>{},
        thrust::maximum<int>{}
    );

    int minimumApproach1 = thrust::reduce(maxima.begin(), maxima.end(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), thrust::minimum<int>{});

    cudaEventRecord(b);
    cudaEventSynchronize(b);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&t, a,b);
    std::cout << "time approach 1 (standard): " << t << " ms. minimum: " <<minimumApproach1 << "\n";


    //Approach 2. Fuse max Reduce_by_key with the computation of the minimaSlots smallest maxima. then min reduce the stored smallest maxima
    //constexpr size_t minimaSlots = 1; 
    //constexpr size_t minimaSlots = 1024; 
    constexpr size_t minimaSlots = 1024*1024;
   
    thrust::device_vector<int> minima_of_maxima(minimaSlots);
    thrust::fill(minima_of_maxima.begin(), minima_of_maxima.end(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    auto minimaOfMaximaIterator = thrust::make_transform_output_iterator(
        thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
        UpdateMinimumOp<minimaSlots>{minima_of_maxima.data().get()}
    );

    cudaEventRecord(a);

    thrust::reduce_by_key(
        keys.begin(),
        keys.end(),
        values.begin(),
        thrust::make_discard_iterator(),
        minimaOfMaximaIterator,
        thrust::equal_to<int>{},
        thrust::maximum<int>{}
    );

    int minimumApproach2 = thrust::reduce(minima_of_maxima.begin(), minima_of_maxima.end(), std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), thrust::minimum<int>{});

    cudaEventRecord(b);
    cudaEventSynchronize(b);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&t, a,b);
    std::cout << "time approach 2 (fused): " << t << " ms. minimum: " << minimumApproach2 << "\n";

    cudaEventDestroy(a);
    cudaEventDestroy(b);
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the first reduce_by_key is unnecessary so it does solve the problem in one kernel call? Although the atomic restriction is too restrictive for me and an ideal solution for me would be without atomics and raw memory pointers.

Comment: @Frimousse You can simply update the callback to store an iterator instead of a pointer and use a lock for serialization. But there has to be serialization if you want to stick with that approach, let it be atomics or something else.

Comment: @Frimousse You could also implement your own reduce by key, compute per-block minima and use a simple device-wide reduction to compute the global minimum. I am not going to write that for you.

Comment: I see. The need for serialization makes this solution unusable for me unfortunately.

Comment: @Frimousse I added some timings. the fused approach is faster if atomic contention can be reduced